# How to select drop-down based on input value of another input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have google a lot but I am not able to understand how to do it.

The code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>  
    </head>


  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#emp_id').blur(function(){

            alert($(this).val());
            $('#emp_name').val($(this).val());
        });
        $('#emp_name').change(function(){

            $('#emp_id').val($(this).val());            
        } );

    });
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="emp_id" />
    <select id="emp_name" name="emp_name">
        <option value="00000" >Please Select </option>
        <option value="e0001" >James Smith</option>         
        <option value="e0002" >Roger Sm</option>
        <option value="e0003" >Elina Lobo</option>
    </select>

  </body>
 </html>
```

and running jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kamleshahire/J3qLv/1/ 
I have two components:

1. **Input box** : user can enter employee id, once employee code entered by user the drop-down has changed based on Employee code. Employee id is part of drop-down.
2. **Drop-down**: it conatins employee id and  value as Employee name.

**I want to show the error message if the input value is not present in the prepopulated drop-down list.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to post your code...

Comment: Is employee id used as select value, and employee name as Display value?

Comment: @elclanrs I will upload now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
    $('#emp_id').change(function(){
        if($('option[value='+$(this).val()+']').length){
            $('#emp_name').val($(this).val());
        }
        else{
            alert('Employee not found.');
        }
    });
```

I edited my answer to meet your updated requirement.. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3qLv/2/)!!

Answer (score 0):

**The complete solution is**

and JSFiddle is

**http://jsfiddle.net/kamleshahire/J3qLv/4/**

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>  
    </head>


  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#emp_id').blur(function(){

            //alert($(this).val());
            var inputValue = $(this).val();

            $('#emp_name').each(function(){
                if(this.value == inputValue){

                    $('#emp_name').val($(this).val()); 
                    return false;
                }
                alert("Please iput valid value");
                $('#emp_name').val('-1');

            });

        });
        $('#emp_name').change(function(){

            $('#emp_id').val($(this).val());            
        } );

    });
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="emp_id" />
    <select id="emp_name" name="emp_name">
        <option value="-1" >Please Select </option>
        <option value="e0001" >James Smith</option>         
        <option value="e0002" >Roger Sm</option>
        <option value="e0003" >Elina Lobo</option>
    </select>

  </body>
 </html>
```